# How to open a new page and pass data between them in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am upgrading the searchbar of my project. I would like that when I press on one of the result a new page is opened that contains all the data of the selected object. Here is the code of the function which show the result of the search in a Link, and in theory when I press on a name I should go to the page passing the object to the new page.

```
{
  filteredData.length != 0 && (
    <div className="dataResult">
      {filteredData.slice(0, 3).map((obj, key) => {
        return (
          <Link
            className="dataItem"
            to={{ pathname: "/SelectedObj", state: obj }}
          >
            {obj.Name}
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So this part of code works, but the new page result without nothing, and i can not understand how to access to the object I have passed to the new page. Here the code of the new page.

```
function SelectedUser() {
  return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
}
```

The thing I don't understand is why it doesn't show me Hello world, other than how to access the passed object.

EDIT: I checked and I forgot to update the routing part. Now everything works, thanks.

Comment: Please add the routing part (where you defined the routes generally in App.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the object passed to the new page,

use **useLocation** hook which is a function that returns the location object that contains information about the current URL. Whenever the URL changes, a new location object will be returned.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

    function SelectedUser() {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.state);

        return (
          <h1>Hello world</h1>
       )
    }
```

Comment: Okay but when I press on the result it changes page, but that page is blank and "does not work".

Comment: @Dodo1991 The error might be caused by incorrectly exporting or importing the component when defining routes, otherwise, the code posted is correct. Also in the comment, I requested the code defining routes.

Answer (score 1):

## **From Parent to Child Using Props**

Try to imagine the directory structure of the app as follows: the parent component actually renders the child components in the app.

```
App
 └── Parent
   ├── Child1
   └── Child2
```

This is the simplest and most basic direction of data flow in React.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {state = { data : "Hello World" } 
render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
                 <Child1/>            //no data to send             
                 <Child2 dataFromParent = {this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );    }
}
```

Use the variable `this.props.dataFromParent` to obtain the data passed from parent to child.

```
class Child2 extends React.Component {
 render() {
         
         return (
             <div>
                 Data from parent is:{this.props.dataFromParent}
             </div>
         );
     }
 }
```

## **From Child to Parent Using Callbacks**

Say you want to send a message from child1 to parent with the message "Hello, how are you?" Take the following steps:

In the Parent.js, set a callback function to take in the parameter that you have accessed from the child.
Send the callback function to the child1.js as a prop.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
state = { message: "" }
callbackFunction = (childData) => {
      this.setState({message: childData})
},


 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <Child1 parentCallback = {this.callbackFunction}/>
                 <p> {this.state.message} </p>
            </div>
        );
}
}
```

Pass your data using `this.props.callback(dataToParent)` in the child1.js.

```
class Child1 extends React.Component{sendData = () => {
         this.props.parentCallback("Hey Popsie, How’s it going?");
    },

render() { 
//Any time you wish to send data from child to parent component, call the sendData function.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

for the link

```
<Link to={"dataitem"}
    state={{ state : "value" }}
>Navigate</Link>
```

and in the dataitem page use the useLocation to get the data like this

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

   const location = useLocation();

   console.log(location.state);
```

Comment: this React Router V6 btw